# Check if multiple values appear in a comma seperated value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for the most efficient way to search a comma-separated value in a column, with a comma-separated value list.

Users enter a job, sub, and Pkglist, comma-separated. If one of the package values exist, I want to pull the ID Used, and increment the Version.

Assuming a datatable like below, and an input of Job 99999, sub 350, and PKGList 001,005,220,429, what would be the best where clause to retrieve ID 42169?

| ID | Version | Job | Sub | PKGList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42169 | 1 | 99999 | 350 | 114,220,569 |
| 42169 | 2 | 99999 | 350 | 220 |
| 42171 | 1 | 99999 | 350 | 192, 487 |

I could split the input PKGList on the comma, and do multiple OR statements i.e

```
SELECT * 
FROM sampleTable 
WHERE PKGList LIKE '%001%' 
   OR PKGList LIKE '%002%' 
   OR PKGList LIKE '%220%' 
   OR PKGList LIKE '%429%'
```

But I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: *"But I'm wondering if there is an easier way"* Yes, fix your design.

Comment: @ThomA agreed, but I don't have access to alter or create tables. I am working with what I was given

Comment: Can you give some information on what Database product you're using? The answer will probably be specific to the DB software.

Comment: @TerenceSimpson the OP has tagged their database engine...

Comment: If you can't fix the problem (you *really* need to), then the alternative would be to split the string (there are literally 1,000's of Q&As on that) and then use an `IN` against that split value.

Comment: Also, in addition to being an "easier" way, a normalised design will certainly be the most efficient, as you'll be able to index the column(s) and use SARGable clauses in the `WHERE`. If you aren't in a position to fix the problem, then you should be speaking to whoever is in such a position.

Comment: Note: `ID` must be unique.

Comment: You'll likely want to use [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to do this. You can use that function in the `FROM` clause to split the string into their own rows, upon which you can search with your `WHERE` clause like a normal properly normalized table. It's just going to be a little slow.

Comment: The query would become trivial if the database desing was normalized to at least 1NF. What keeps you from doing that?

Comment: @TerenceSimpson Don't you see the tag `sql-server` on the question?

Comment: Use string split function to split PKGLst,then you will get the answer after that

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP supoert if your database support this.

```
SELECT *
FROM sampleTable
WHERE Job = 99999
  AND Sub = 350
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE('001,005,220,429', ',') AS pkg
    WHERE sampleTable.PKGList LIKE '%' || pkg || '%'
  );
```

REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE function is used to split the comma-separated values in your input.

EXISTS checks if there is at least one match.

Comment: Tag was SQL Server not PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution based on SQL Server's XML and XQuery.

It is using a so called *Quantified Expressions*.

For the reference: [Quantified Expressions (XQuery)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/quantified-expressions-xquery?view=sql-server-ver16)

> **Existential quantifier** Given two sequences, if any item in the first
> sequence has a match in the second sequence, based on the comparison
> operator that is used, the returned value is True.

`CROSS APPLY` is casting PKGList column as XML data type. For example, the first row PKGList column value becomes as follows:

```
<root>
  <source>
    <r>001</r>
    <r>002</r>
    <r>220</r>
    <r>429</r>
  </source>
  <target>
    <r>114</r>
    <r>220</r>
    <r>569</r>
  </target>
</root>
```

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, PKGList VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT @tbl (PKGList) VALUES
('114,220,569'),
('220'),
('192, 487');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @Separator CHAR(1) = ','
    , @searchFor VARCHAR(MAX) = '001,002,220,429';;

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
        , c.value('some $r in /root/source/r/text()
              satisfies $r = /root/target/r/text()', 'BIT') AS Result
    FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><source><r><![CDATA[' 
        + REPLACE(@searchFor, @Separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') 
        + ']]></r></source>'
        + '<target><r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(PKGList, @Separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') 
        + ']]></r></target></root>' AS XML) AS xmldata
      ) AS t1(c)
)
SELECT * FROM rs
WHERE Result = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @input nvarchar(1000) = '001,005,220,429,192'

select 
    * 
from 
    sampleTable 
where exists (select 1 from splitstring(@input, ',') a 
        inner join splitstring(sampleTable.PKGList, ',') b on a.value = b.value)



create FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX), @seperator varchar(1) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([value] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT
   
 WHILE CHARINDEX(@seperator, @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@seperator, @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```